# Will I see any performance if I disable pagefile and use Readyboost instead?

Tags: windows, readyboost

My laptop is an IBM ThinkPad T500 using Windows 7, x64 with 8 GB RAM.

I have the OS manage the pagefile which is currently 8GB in size. I don't use sleep and hibernation.

Will I see any performance change if I disable the pagefile and use a 16GB SD card for Readyboost?

Comment: **Do not disable your pagefile.**  It has a specific purpose, and is nowhere close to the features provided by Readyboost.  The two can compliment one another (as well as the superfetch feature), but you need all three of these things enabled to make your system work best (pagefile, superfectch, and in some cases, Readyboost).

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to replace your page file with readyboost, I'm not even sure windows will attempt to. The benefit of readyboost is that small bits of information can be accessed fast, while large bits remain on the hdd as the transfer rates outdo the access time penalty.

Windows 8 might be a different story with native USB 3.0 support + USB 3.0 drives which actually utilize the available bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

ReadyBoost is for machines with low memory.  With 8 GB of RAM, your machine will not benefit at all from ReadyBoost.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the USB Stick or SD card are not even fast enough to make Readyboost worthwhile.

I know when Vista launched, there were flash drives that were certified as Readyboost capable, meaning that they had the speed of the device had to meet certain requirements. Now, you can connect any old USB device to the system and it will ask you if you want to use Readyboost even if it's just another rotating disk.

If you want to reap the benefits of flash memory, you need to plunk down some cash for a SSD. In your case, Lenovo has an accessory for your notebook that would let you install a 2.5" drive into your optical bay. Get as big of an SSD as you can afford (80-120GB deepening on your needs, more if you are Mr. Moneybags) and drop it in.

You can clone your install over or do a fresh install. After that, set the system to keep your docs, pics, movies, etc on your Hard drive so that the SSD has room for Windows and Apps - the things that are important to have on an SSD.

[Lenovo SATA bay adapter](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=38&Code=43N3412&current-category-id=2478535BAB3C417CA9D77F5867D31462&&hide_menu_area=yes)

Answer (score 0):

No, don't replace your pagefile with Readyboost. That's a BAD idea. That's not what Readyboost is for when it was designed and not what it's for today.